# How do I calculate offset to center views in an HStack?

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 views that are each centered on consecutive iPhone screens. **How do I calculate the offset to display "2" as center width in the preview?**

[image]

```
struct debugView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    private let choices: [String] = [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                AssessmentChoiceView(choice: choices[0]).position(x: (geometry.size.width / 2) + (CGFloat(0) * geometry.size.width), y: geometry.size.height / 2.3)
                AssessmentChoiceView(choice: choices[1]).position(x: (geometry.size.width / 2) + (CGFloat(1) * geometry.size.width), y: geometry.size.height / 2.3)
                AssessmentChoiceView(choice: choices[2]).position(x: (geometry.size.width / 2) + (CGFloat(2) * geometry.size.width), y: geometry.size.height / 2.3)
            }
            .offset(x: -(geometry.size.width / 2) - (CGFloat(1) * geometry.size.width))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve, You can usually achieve centering with alignments and spacers, `GeometryReader` is ver inefficient. `SwiftUI.Layout` is the alternative.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a rough sketch of what you're looking for? Also... perhaps a `TabView` is what you're looking for. `TabViewStyle` has a `.page` style which I think might give you what you're looking for without needing Geometry Reader... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle

Comment: I want to be able to swipe left or right to have each "choice" string slide into the screen with an animation

Comment: @Shane `TabView` with a `TabViewStyle` of `.page` does that for you for free.